# How to get value from view to view Model in Aurelia JS?

Tags: jquery, aurelia

I have following code in view :

```
<div class="text-input"><label>NUmber: </label> 2456</div>
```

How to get 2456in my view model or .JS file.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use the `input` tag along with `value.bind`:

```
<label for="inputNumber">Number</label>
<input type="text" id="inputNumber" value.bind="inputNumber">
```

This will create an `inputNumber` property in the view model.

See [Aurelia data binding](http://aurelia.io/docs/binding).